# Line with its length self-adjusting to parent-Panel's ActualWidth property (data-binding)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a vertical StackPanel and I want it to contain Line-child with .X2 value binded to parent-StackPanel's ActualWidth. Something like:

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
sp.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
(...)
Line line = new Line();
line.X1 = 0;
line.X2 = <Some binding to sp.ActualWidth>;
// line.Y1 = line.Y2 - will it set it's value to 0 by default?
line.StrokeThickness = 2;
(...)
sp.Children.Add(line);
```

Should I use INotifyPropertyChanged interface? Is this the most proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INotifyPropertyChanged is not necessary.

Just create a binding and setbinding to X2Property of the line.

```
        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        sp.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        Line line = new Line();
        line.X1 = 0;
        var bind = new Binding()
        {
            Source = sp,
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth")
        };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(line, Line.X2Property, bind);
        line.StrokeThickness = 2;
        line.Stroke=Brushes.Black;
        line.Margin=new Thickness(10);
        sp.Children.Add(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a Line with a bound `X2` property and a `StrokeThickness` of 2 would be a Rectangle with a `Height` of 2. Its width is automatically set to the StackPanel width.

```
var sp = new StackPanel
{
    Orientation = Orientation.Vertical
};
...
var line = new Rectangle
{
    Height = 2,
    Fill = Brushes.Black
};
sp.Children.Add(line);
```